# Rotating array elements individually

Tags: modifiers

Hello I am new to blender and I am trying to make this shape:
[image]

I made this one duplicating and trying to shape it by rotating them so it is very faulty.
I tried doing it with array but this is how it ended up looking:
[image]

Is it possible to make it nicer with array or any other suggestions? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your shape, move it away from its origin in *Edit* mode:

[image]

At the same location as the origin, create an empty. Give your object an Array modifier, choose the count, disable *Relative Offset*, enable *Object Offset* and choose the empty as *Object*:

[image]

Rotate the empty on Z, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to rotate 5° by 5°:

[image]

Comment: +1 but...does this also work with dollar bills? And if i realize instances afterwards, do i really have multiplied my money? or do i have to 3d print them? questions...over questions? and maybe this isn't a focused question and not even about Blender!? ...aaaargh

Comment: @Chris we don't need money now that we can live in Blender, we can build or own objects without eveb paying

Comment: well, that's much better than in every state of the world, where you have to pay taxes on everything for just being existing.... ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it but I assume I am doing something wrong because I ended up with an array of elements that gets larger and larger that does seem to be rotating around the cursot tho

Comment: @fawkemvegas you need to apply the scale of your empty (Ctrl A) otherwise it will be taken into account

Comment: @moonboots yes that did it! thank you very much for the help!!!